# How can I edit the gnome-panel "Places" menu?

Tags: configuration, gnome-panel, places

How can I edit the gnome-panel "Places" menu? (I have the same SSH server showing twice and it's annoying.)

**Edit**: More precisely, how can I remove the servers I added through "Places / Connect to Server..."

**Edit 2:** Here's a screenshot of my Nautilus showing the duplicate servers. By the way, I just realized those have nothing to do with the "Places / Connect to Server..." feature:
[image]

Answer (score 14):

- Open **nautilus browser** and in left you will see places menu.
- Goto **Bookmarks>>Edit Bookmarks**

[image]
Remove the Entry which you have twice,
[image]

Or in **terminal** type the following,and remove the entry.

```
gedit ~/.gtk-bookmarks
```

**Removing servers from the list:**

- You can remove the remote servers from the list by opening the **Network** folder from **Places>>Network**.
- Right-click the server you want to remove and then clicking unmount volume.

Comment: Great info but I still haven't figured how to remove the duplicate server as it is not a "bookmark".

Comment: `@Olivier Lalonde` I cant really get you.Can you post your snap of Places Menu.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open up Nautilus: *Places -> Home Folder* (or any other bookmark listed there).
2. *Bookmarks -> Edit Bookmarks*.

   [image]

You can also right-click the bookmarks on the side panel, and remove them that way.

Comment: Thanks, but it won't let me remove the servers I added :(